# Concatenate + time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

We currently have the following columns:

```
CustomerID         int
ArrivalDateTime    datetime
CheckPoint         varchar(20)
DepartureDateTime  datetime
```

CheckPoint column records 24hr format time based on specific queries.

```
CustomerID  ArrivalDateTime      CheckPoint      DepartureDateTime
1           2015-05-03 08:15     0800            2015-05-03 08:30
2           2015-05-04 13:15     1300            2015-05-04 15:30
```

What I need is replace time from ArrivalDateTime with CheckPoint time. So that it reads as below:

```
CustomerID  ArrivalDateTime          DepartureDateTime
    1       2015-05-03 08:00         2015-05-03 08:30
    2       2015-05-04 13:00         2015-05-04 15:30
```

So that I can get the time difference from ArrivalDateTime to DepartureDateTime.
Expected Results:

```
CustomerID      ArrivalDateTime          DepartureDateTime     TimeInMinutes
        1       2015-05-03 08:00         2015-05-03 08:30      30
        2       2015-05-04 13:00         2015-05-04 15:30      150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT  CustomerID
        ,CAST(CAST(ArrivalDateTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(CONCAT(LEFT([CheckPoint], 2), ':', RIGHT([CheckPoint], 2)) AS DATETIME) AS ArrivalDateTime
        ,DepartureDateTime
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(CAST(ArrivalDateTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(CONCAT(LEFT([CheckPoint], 2), ':', RIGHT([CheckPoint], 2)) AS DATETIME), DepartureDateTime) AS TimeInMinutes
FROM @tbl
```

---

Sample data with output

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (CustomerID INT,  ArrivalDateTime DATETIME,      [CheckPoint] Varchar(20),     DepartureDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT @tbl
SELECT 1           ,'2015-05-03 08:15',     '0800'      ,      '2015-05-03 08:30' UNION ALL
SELECT 2           ,'2015-05-04 13:15',     '1300'      ,      '2015-05-04 15:30'

SELECT  CustomerID
        ,CAST(CAST(ArrivalDateTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(CONCAT(LEFT([CheckPoint], 2), ':', RIGHT([CheckPoint], 2)) AS DATETIME) AS ArrivalDateTime
        ,DepartureDateTime
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(CAST(ArrivalDateTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(CONCAT(LEFT([CheckPoint], 2), ':', RIGHT([CheckPoint], 2)) AS DATETIME), DepartureDateTime) AS TimeInMinutes
FROM @tbl

CustomerID  ArrivalDateTime         DepartureDateTime       TimeInMinutes
1           2015-05-03 08:00:00.000 2015-05-03 08:30:00.000 30
2           2015-05-04 13:00:00.000 2015-05-04 15:30:00.000 150
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7146f/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked well and that is how I wanted to code. Functions you used are simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select 
    CustomerID
    , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, ArrivalDateTime), STUFF(CheckPoint_,3,0,':')) ArrivalDateTime
    , DepartureDateTime
    , DATEDIFF(mi, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, ArrivalDateTime), STUFF([CheckPoint],3,0,':')), DepartureDateTime) as TimeInMinutes
from t;
```

If you don't want to repeat the functions you can move them to a cte or derived table like so:

```
select 
    CustomerID
    , ArrivalDateTime
    , DepartureDateTime
    , DATEDIFF(mi, ArrivalDateTime, DepartureDateTime) as TimeInMinutes
from (
    select 
        CustomerID
       , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, ArrivalDateTime), STUFF([CheckPoint],3,0,':')) ArrivalDateTime
       , DepartureDateTime
    from t) a
;
```

Comment: **DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, ArrivalDateTime), STUFF([CheckPoint],3,0,':'))** v.nice

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT customerid, 
                ArrivalDateTime = Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Cast(ArrivalDateTime AS  DATE)) 
                                       + ' ' + Stuff(CheckPoint_, 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME), 
                departuredatetime 
         FROM   yourtable) 
SELECT customerid, 
       arrivaldatetime, 
       departuredatetime, 
       TimeInMinutes = Datediff(minute, arrivaldatetime, departuredatetime) 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   CA.RevisedArrivalDateTime
 , DepartureDateTime
 , datediff(minute,CA.RevisedArrivalDateTime,DepartureDateTime)
from yourtable
cross apply (
  select dateadd(minute
                 , convert(int,left([CheckPoint],2)) * 60
                 + convert(int,right([CheckPoint],2))
                 ,dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, ArrivalDateTime ), 0))
  ) CA (RevisedArrivalDateTime)
```

by converting CheckPoint into a number of minutes one can avoid useing varchar conversion to datetimes which should make this more efficient.

Also, by use cross apply it is possible to reuse the calculated new datetime by its alias.

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20263/1)